# Excel creating graphs for each row new

Tags: excel, for-loop, graph, row, each

I have to make a project for biology.
I need to create 21 graphs. Each one for one row.

The graphs will be the same, but only changed data from in each row.
That's mean, If I have a table with 21 rows I need 21 graphs and only change value from each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could literally create a set of graphs - one for each line if you wished however, this would be a fair pull on your processor so probably isn't the best of ideas.

If you are using Excel 2013, I'd have a look at the 'Sparklines' portion of the insert tab, where you can add a couple of different mini one line graphs.

Hope this helps